# Capturing output of a windows command to a variable

Tags: cmd

I was looking for a Windows CMD equivalent to something like

```
var=`ls`
```

in Unix. Is there a way to do so without having to iterate using `for /f`?

Comment: please specify your question correctly `ls` equivalent command in dos is `dir`

Comment: if it sis a single line output.. then use `CD > tmpFile`
`SET /p myvar= < tmpFile`

Comment: Sadly, the answer is No :-(  Unless it is a single line, and you are willing to use a temp file as Prakash suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with PowerShell (and script it in a .ps1).

```
PS C:\> $myVar = & dir | format-table -hidetableheaders -property name
PS C:\> echo $myVar

Program Files
Program Files (x86)
Users
Windows
```

Comment: Yes, but the question was about CMD, and PowerShell ≠ CMD.

Comment: There are comments about the fact that this is not possible with CMD batch. So, you can't do it vanilla, BUT, if the need is to retrieve something multiline in a variable to reuse it later, in 2013/2014 we can assume that PowerShell is natively available on the machine, and there is many (most of the time, simple) ways to do that with PowerShell. So, instead of leaving the asker with just a "NO", we give him some new possibilities to do the thing he wants to, without installing third party software.

Comment: I agree that "No" may not be very good as *the* answer, but the difference between PowerShell and CMD is such that I cannot help feeling that suggesting a PowerShell answer to a CMD question is like suggesting a C solution to a Pascal problem. (And I am talking not so much about difference in capabilities as about difference in syntax between the two shells, because that requires new knowledge.)

Comment: You are absolutely right and I sincerely apologize for suggesting any alternative. The correct and only possible answer to this question is : "NO, you can't do that. Don't try anything else, shutdown your computer, watch the floor and cry."